# Why the rows of my board are reversed when I try to empty the "fully-filled" rows only, in javascript

Tags: javascript, tetris

I'm trying to program an algorithm that does check all the fields in a row, except where you find the values '#', if they're all full. If they are, then that row becomes an empty one and gets unshifted inside the board. However, when I execute the function with an initial board given as a parameter, the rows are reversed.

To illustrate:

if this is my initial board:

```
[
        Array(18).fill('#'),
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','1','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','1','1','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','1','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','#'],
        Array(18).fill('#')
    ]
```

It is turned into this:

```
[
        Array(18).fill('#'),
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','1','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','1','1','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','1','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#'],
        Array(18).fill('#')
    ]
```

Instead of making those '1' valued fields stay the same. Why that does happen?

Here's the function(My board given as a parameter is the initial board in the example right on top):

```
function checkFilledRow(board) {
        // The new board that'll be returned
        let newBoard = []
        for (var row=1;row<board.length - 1;row++) {
            const currentRow = board[row]
            let newRow = []
            for (var i=1;i<currentRow.length - 1;i++) {
                if (currentRow[i] === '') {
                    // If  there's an empty spot, push the row as-is and break
                    newBoard.push(currentRow)
                    break
                } else if (i === currentRow.length - 2) {
                    // If it is the last element of the row(not having taken '#' into account) and still haven't came across one empty spot, an empty array should be unshifted
                    newRow = ['#','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','#']
                    newBoard.unshift(newRow)
                }
            }
        }
        newBoard.unshift(Array(18).fill('#'))
        newBoard.push(Array(18).fill('#'))
        return newBoard
    }
```

By the way, I tried using reverse() method, although the display is no longer messy, I still struggle with the same issue(the output shows that rows still get reversed).

Is there any suggestion that you can come up with?

UDPATE:

Here's my other function where I started to think the problem exists:

```
function dropdownElements(board) {
        let newBoard = board
        for (var row=1;row<board.length - 1;row++) {    
            for (var col=1;col<board[0].length - 1;col++) {
                const currentBrick = board[row][col]
                if (currentBrick !== '' && currentBrick !== 'b') {
                    const elemCords = checkForElementType(board, currentBrick)
                    for (var i=0;i<elemCords.length;i++) {
                        const current = elemCords[i]
                        // The problem is that when there's a brick underneath which there's another one of the same element, it does the wrong thing. Solve it
                        if ((newBoard[current[0] + 1][current[1]] !== '' && newBoard[current[0] + 1][current[1]] !== currentBrick)) {
                            // Turn bricks into 'b'
                            for (var b=0;b<newBoard.length;b++) {
                                for (var bc=0;bc<newBoard[0].length;bc++) {
                                    let elem = newBoard[b][bc]
                                    newBoard[b][bc] = (elem === currentBrick) ? 'b' : elem
                                }
                            }
                            return newBoard
                        } else if (i === elemCords.length - 1) {
                            // Create the new board by lowering the y value of all its bricks
                            // When two squares are on top of each other, it reduces the number of squares in the column
                            for (var r=elemCords.length - 1;r>=0;r--) {
                                const applying = elemCords[r]
                                newBoard[applying[0]][applying[1]] = ''
                                newBoard[applying[0] + 1][applying[1]] = currentBrick
                            }
                            return newBoard
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To explain what it does; it lowers all the Tetris elements(yes, this is for a Tetris game) that have not yet been blocked. Also if they get blocked, their value turns into 'b'-meaning that they can no longer fall-.

I'd highly appreciate it if you could help me out :)

NEW UPDATE:

I logged `newBoard === board` to console to check which one is it and I was shocked to find out that the error is in the initial function that I posted. Also I printed out the rows one-by-one to compare and the result would be the same; it is reversed in situations where it should be the same.

Comment: I think your problem is elsewhere - the above code does not produce the result you say, https://jsfiddle.net/d14L9w0a/

Comment: I think I found out where it is, will post an update. Thx for the reminder :)

Comment: By the way, the problem is neither in the function that I posted when updating the question. I typed `console.log(board === newBoard)` and it returned `true`. Got to find something else.

Comment: By the way, I re-checked it again and typed the same thing(`console.log(board === newBoard)`) for the initial function that I posted, and was shocked to find out that the problem was there. I truly convinced myself to believe that the error was somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, the first function looked okay. I will try check the other one later but it's kind of hard to read. You could try breaking it up by making functions out of some of the logic. If you get stuck I have a working game here that might help you: https://github.com/melcor76/js-tetris